# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.0'

Tags: python

My code is

```
# put your python code here
a=int(input())                   #a for first number
b=int(input())                   #b for second number
op=input()                       #c for operation
if op=='+': print(a+b)
elif op=='-': print(a-b)
elif op=='/':
    if b!=0: print(a/b)
    else: print('Деление на 0!') #'Division by 0!'
elif op=='*': print(a*b)
elif op=='mod': print(a%b)
elif op=='pow': print(a**b)
elif op=='div': print(a//b)
```

on my computer it works good, but I'm trying to learn on courses, where an interpreter gives me an error like this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.0'
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `a=int(input())` and entering "5.0" will work in 2.7, but not 3.X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to cast your string represented as a float in to an int. This won't work. As specified by the help of int():

```
If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
 |  bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal
```

Look at the following example to help illustrate this:

```
>>> x = int("5.5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.5'
>>> x = float("5.5")
>>> x
5.5
>>>
```

Running your code with the following test input after changing the int to float, yields the following:

```
# inputs
5.5
6.6
mod
# output
5.5
```

Comment: Ok. But then new problem appears:
'ZeroDivisionError: float modulo'

Comment: then use `int(a)` and `int(b)` when you reach that case.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to convert a floating point string into an integer.  Since you're trying to create a calculator, use `float()` instead of `int()`.  If you really want just the integer use`int(float(input()))`.